# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta por varios meses a través de checkboxes en PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo varios checkbox de todos los meses, pero quiero que cuando el usuario dé click en Marzo, Abril y Junio, por ejemplo, salgan los registros de todos esos tres meses.

Parte del código PHP/HTML:

```
<form method="post" class="form" action="reportes/reporte_excel_mes.php">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="opcion" value="01" checked>Enero</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="opcion" value="02">Febrero</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="opcion" value="03">Marzo</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="opcion" value="04">Abril</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="opcion" value="05">Mayo</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="opcion" value="06">Junio</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="opcion" value="07">Julio</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="opcion" value="08">Agosto</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="opcion" value="09">Sept.</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="opcion" value="10">Oct.</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="opcion" value="11">Nov.</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="opcion" value="12">Dic.</label>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="reporte_mes">
    </form>
```

Parte de la consulta:

```
<?php

header(xxxxx);
header(xxxx);
header(xxxx);

require 'xxx';

if(isset($_POST['reporte_mes'])){

$sql = "SELECT bien_catal.bien, categorias.nombre_categoria, marca_catal.marca, color_catal.color, modelo_catal.modelo, 
area_catal.area, condicion.condicion, products.caracteristicas, products.stock, products.precio_producto, products.date_added,
products.codigo_producto, products.observaciones FROM products 
LEFT JOIN bien_catal ON (products.fk_bien = bien_catal.id_bien) 
LEFT JOIN categorias ON (products.fk_categoria = categorias.id_categoria)  
LEFT JOIN marca_catal ON (products.fk_marca = marca_catal.id_marca)
LEFT JOIN color_catal ON (products.fk_color = color_catal.id_color)
LEFT JOIN modelo_catal ON (products.fk_modelo = modelo_catal.id_modelo)
LEFT JOIN area_catal ON (products.fk_area = area_catal.id_area)
LEFT JOIN condicion ON (products.fk_condicion = condicion.id_condicion)";

...
```

Ya no sé cómo hacer el WHERE para buscar la fecha dependiendo de todos los meses que se hayan seleccionado. :(

La tabla products es la que lleva el campo date_added en donde ya están agregadas las fechas tipo... 2017/06/16.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes sacar los meses seleccionados con un $('input[name=opcion]:checked').val().join() eso te va a dar los valores de los meses en una cadena separa con comas, ya puedes hacer el WHERE con un MONTH(date_add) IN (valores de los meses) (no estoy seguro que asi sea en mysql) pero creo que puedes darte una idea.